# Check out or Solandra(0.7) gives me NoSuchMethodError on start up

Tags: nosuchmethoderror, solandra, startup-error

8:55:18,996 failed solandra.SolandraDispatchFilter-144715990: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.common.util.DOMUtil.substituteProperties(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;Ljava/util/Properties;)V
 WARN 08:55:19,012 failed org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context@59c958af{/solandra,null}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.common.util.DOMUtil.substituteProperties(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;Ljava/util/Properties;)V
ERROR 08:55:19,012 Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.common.util.DOMUtil.substituteProperties(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;Ljava/util/Properties;)V

I am using java 1.6_25, so i don't understand why i am having this.
Can anyone help??? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

im using the solandra 0.7 from Git, I can run solandra just fine from command line with no issues....only when i try to start it in Eclipse.

I am betting this is an eclipse issue with using the wrong JRE,somehow. :/